# Schengen visa from the Czech Republic for travel only within the Czech Republic. I want to travel to Vienna and Berlin. Can I do that?

Tags: visas, schengen, czech-republic

I am travelling to the Czech Republic and have got my Schengen visa, but now I am planning to alter the itinerary and also visit Vienna and Berlin. Can I do this?

Comment: What's "Type of visa"? What's "Number of entries"? These should be on your visa.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what it is that makes you conclude that the visa you have is "for travel only within the Czech Republic"? If it's only because such travel was all you described in your visa application, then this conclusion is _not_ true.

Comment: @alamar type and number of entries are unlikely to be relevant unless the traveler planson leaving the Schengen area between the Czech Republic and Austria or Germany, which in turn seems unlikely.  The more important item is "valid for," although the meaning of this item does depend on the visa's type.

Comment: The question is self-contradictory. If your visa is "for travel only within the Czech Republic", then it is not a "Schengen visa".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you applied for a Limited territorial validity visa (LTV). Which means you can only visit the Czech Republic if that's what's specified on the visa.

Comment: What made you think so?

Comment: Schengen visa from the Czech Republic **for travel only within the Czech Republic**. I want to travel to Vienna and Berlin. Can I do that?

Comment: there's nothing that tells us the visa is limited. We're just hinted on how it was requested.

Comment: I don't think you can _apply for_ an LTV visa. It's something the consulate may end up issuing if they find they _cannot_ issue the general Schengen visa being requested.

Answer (score -2):

There is a specification number or code printed on the visa which states the type of visa you have obtained.

The LTV, which limits traveling to the issuing state, applies to persons entering the country due to humanitarian reasons, under international obligation or in emergency cases without holding valid traveling documents.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE! Please don't link to schengenvisainfo.com for facts. It is a private website that exists to generate ad impressions, and what it says is often many years out of date. (For example, it claimed that category "B" visas for overland transit existed, for at least 6 years after they were abolished).